# Google sheets permission authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I press a button that requires my authorization in google sheets, how can I see all the permissions I have given to scripts to execute so that I can revoke them? I understand these are only local executions.

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to retrieve all scopes which was permitted for the GAS project.
- You want to revoke the permitted scopes.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### 1. Retrieve all scopes which was permitted for the GAS project:

When the use of scopes were permitted, this is reflected to the access token. Using this, you can retrieve all scopes which was permitted for the GAS project from the access token. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var res = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
Logger.log(res.scope)
```

- When you run the script, all authorized scopes of the GAS project can be retrieved.
- About `url`, you can also use `var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`.

### 2. Revoke permitted scopes:

When the scopes are authorized for the GAS project, the project can be seen at ["Third-party apps with account access"](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions). For example, when the project is manually removed, the authorized scopes are revoked. This means that the access token is revoked. By this, when the script in the GAS project is run, the authorization screen is opened again. Using this, you can revoke the access token using the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(res.getResponseCode());
```

- When you run the script, when `res.getResponseCode()` is `200`, it means that the access token was revoked.

  - By this, you can see the GAS project was removed at "Third-party apps with account access" page.
  - When the script in the GAS project is run, you can see the authorization screen is displayed again.

### References:

- [Revoking a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)
- [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)
- [Remove Third-party Apps with Account Access using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/608e65fee105989df1a7b645c20572c2)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Very helpful, but as a simple example to maybe append to your answer, I get an email alert that I have given access to a third party sheet script to delete my spreadsheets in Google Drive, is there a simple user friendly way to revoke that permission?

Comment: @CodeCamper Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot know about `a simple user friendly way to revoke that permission` except for above answer. I have to apologize I couldn't resolve your additional request. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: problem 1) I can't remove myself from a project I was invited to revoke permission, or is there a way to remove myself from a project I do not own? problem(removing from view isn't enough to revoke) 2) if my permission is set to view only how can I retrieve the OAuthToken for a project I do not own but have given authorization in script.google.com I see 1 Scope Requested https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets so I guess the question is how can someone with view only access revoke their permission?

Comment: @CodeCamper Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, the viewers cannot revoke the permission using the script. But it can be revoked by manually deleted at ["Third-party apps with account access"](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions). If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was entirely useful and informative! I asked a new question about importrange permissions now as a different question if you want to try to answer that one.

Comment: @CodeCamper Thank you for replying. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: From January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) So please use the access token to the request header instead of the query parameter. It's as follows. `var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});`