# Reset the authentication for YouTube Data API v3 API Key in Google App Scrip

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to use new YouTube Data API key from my second cloud console project in Google App Scripts, but it returns this error. I'm assuming I need to reset the authentication I did for my old api key from my first project. Could anyone help me how to reset the authentication?
※When I authenticated, I just requested the URL and it automatically sent me to the authentication page.
`Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 129, file "Code")`

Comment: Can you provide your script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, Thank you for your comment.
Actually the script itself is the same as [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041429/google-apps-script-returns-an-error-limit-exceeded-urlfetch-url-length) you helped me before.

It returns the error `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_commentthreads_1);`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I think that API key might not be able to be revoked by Google Apps Script. So as a workaround, in your situation, how about using Advanced Google Service or your access token instead of UrlFetchApp? In this case, the access token can be revoked like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808175). But if this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for you quick help.
I'm not sure why but I solved the issue as below.

I was defining API KEY outside of the function I run since I was running several functions along with the one I showed. But when I defined the key inside of each function, it worked. I apologize for my basic mistake.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.